# Updating with Dataset while using Trim function

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, datagridview

I am using a dataset and a table adapter to populate a datagridview. In my SQL statement I am using the `RTrim` function for two of the columns. For both of them, I am setting the result variable to the same name as the original column name.

This works, but then I cannot update the data using the dataset, because the trimmed values are read-only.

What I want is to fill a datagridview with trimmed values, and then be able to update using the same dataset. This seems simple, yet it will not allow me to do this. Everything updates except the two columns that I used `Trim` on.

Here is the SQL statement I am using.

```
SELECT   
    PK, RTRIM(Description) AS Description, ContractNumber,
    RTRIM(Status) AS Status, Active
FROM
    ConstructionProjects
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN ContractNumber > 0 
         THEN ContractNumber 
         ELSE 99999 
    END
```

I know I can easily trim the cells on the client side in the Windows App., but I was looking for a way to do this at the SQL side, at the query. Is there an easy way to do this, and still be able to call the `Update` method?

Thanks,

Matt Fomich

Comment: A possible workaround could be tried loading the column Description and Status without the trimming operation,then hide them in your gridview. When you update your trimmed (and visible) column copy the value back to the untrimmed (and hidden) column in the same row. Then the update should work as usual.

Comment: That would work, Thanks.  That would probably be a little less overhead than trimming each cell in Description and Status.  I will try this tomorrow and post performance results.
 Thanks!

Comment: Glad you like it.  I will re-post the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible workaround could be tried loading the column Description and Status without the trimming operation,then hide them in your gridview. When you update your trimmed (and visible) column copy the value back to the untrimmed (and hidden) column in the same row. Then the update should work as usual.

Perhaps you should change the name of the column. (the trimmed Description and Status columns)